# Debugging a program to generate Associative Pairs from words in a text file in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5

I have written this code in order to get pairs of artists which appear more than 50 times in my text file. Two artists names are separated by a comma. I am unable to figure why my program is not performing properly as I am extracting the names properly but while printing the names get distorted that is some characters from the names disappear.

Here's My code:

```
#Program Written in Jetbrains Pycharm Community Edition with `Anaconda(Python Version 3.5)`
#Dhruv Marwha

filename="Artist_lists_small.txt" #Name of the file assigned to a variable

with open(filename,encoding='utf8')as infile:
    something=list(set(infile.read().split(","))) #Initialising Something with all unique artist names found in the Text File based on splitting all the words on a ','.

dictionary={}#Dictionary to Store Artist Name Along with It's Line Number

with open(filename,encoding='utf8') as f:#If the word from our list is present in the text file,we add the word+it's line number to the list of values in the dictionary.
    for line_num,xyz in enumerate(f):
        for i in range(len(something)):
            if something[i] in xyz:
                dictionary.setdefault(something[i], []).append(line_num)

for key,value in list(dictionary.items()):#Removing All the keys whose list of values has a length of less than 50
                                          #This is done because if 2 words occur less than 50 times,there's no point in making their combinations.
    if len(value)<50:
        del dictionary[key]

pair_list=[]#List to Store the Collection of All pairs which occur together more than 50 times

for key,value in dictionary.items():
    for key1,value1 in dictionary.items():#Comparing one key with another key in the same dictionary in order to find the intersection between the list of values
        if key==key1:
            continue
        if len(set.intersection(set(value),set(value1)))>50:#If the values between 2 lists intersect more than 50 times,the pair is valid.
            pair_list.append((key,key1))


for k in range(len(pair_list)):#Printing The List Of Pairs.
    print(pair_list[k])

#print(len(pair_list))#Printing the no of pairs which occur more than 50 times.

#############################################################################################################

#Time Complexity-O(n^2)
#Space Complexity-O(n)
```

[Here's the link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx8pCsGkUCElR0gtUmJuM1A5MnM) to the text file in question.

Also do tell me whether this program produces correct output as according to me it produces correct output.

Comment: Can you give an example of an artist name in the text file being distorted?

Comment: @NasefKhan For Example this file contains a artist named Radiohead.HIs Name Appears as Ra.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Do you still require a solution to this?

Comment: Actually I do as this would help me to improve my own code.

Comment: What kind output are you expecting? I'm also a bit confused about what you mean by "pairs of artists".

Comment: @NasefKhan Consider 2 artists such as Metallica and Lady Gaga.This is a artist pair.Now i need to find if a pair like this occurs more than 50 times together.The said pair can occur anywhere in one line i.e it is not location dependent within the line.I need to find all such pairs.

Comment: So a pair of artists is any combination of two artists on the same line?

Comment: @NasefKhan That is Correct and I need to find such pairs which occur together on more than 50 lines.